# Issue "This OperationContextScope is being disposed on a different thread than it was created" even without using await in OperationContextScope

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used below 2 approaches to call external wcf service in mvc 5 project which is using .net framework 4.8.

- In Approach 1, I'm using await outside of the OperationContextScope block
- In Approach 2, there is no await, calling synchronousmethod.

**Approach 1:**

```
Task<ResponseType> response;
using (OperationContextScope ocss = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    foreach(var header in _headers)
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
    }  

    response = client.sendDataAsync(request);
}

var result = await response; //async call
```

**Approach 2:**

```
List<<ResponseType> response;
using (OperationContextScope ocss = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    foreach(var header in _headers)
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
    }  

    response = client.sendData(request).ToList(); //synchronous call
}
```

Above both approaches are working fine locally, but when I deploy to IIS Servers, it is throwing error

> This OperationContextScope is being disposed on a different thread
> than it was created

Comment: Show us your `web.config`. While `async`/`await` is supported in ASP.NET for .NET Framework 4.x, you need to opt-in with `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>` - and I'm not sure how compatible that is with WCF - and may I ask why you're still using WCF?

Comment: @Dai, there is no config setting as aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext in my web.config. Do I need to add this config setting to make my code work. Could you please elaborate on that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know and I can't know: there's 1,001+ reasons why it isn't working for you, but that's the first thing I'd try out.

Comment: I tried by adding aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext setting to true in web.config, unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: @Dai consider that CoreWCF exists, https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF there shouldn't be much to challenge the preference of WCF. People are free.

Comment: @LexLi CoreWCF is a community project, Microsoft isn't developing it.

Comment: @Dai "We recognize how important support is to enterprise customers, and so we are pleased to announce that Microsoft Product Support will be available for CoreWCF customers", different from most community projects, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/

Comment: @LexLi, here I'm just calling external wcf service from a mvc 5 project, not sure how CoreWCF will be used in my case. Pls clarify.

Comment: We were talking about something else. For your project, I think too many details were not shared, so impossible to guess the actual cause. If possible, share the entire project or a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.